# how to grep required pattern only

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

data in File:

```
23445 messages sent
number of messages sent by io is 245
total messages sent is 23456
message are not sent
messages sent 4321
```

i want to extract 'message sent' but this pattern is in most of the lines 
my  output file should be like

```
23445 messages sent
messages sent 4321
```

here means my pattern is can be at starting of line or ending of line not in middile of line. how to extract these patteren

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with the `-E` flag like so:

```
grep -E '^messages sent|messages sent$' myfile.txt
```

Which, given your example input, yields:

```
23445 messages sent
messages sent 4321
```

From the `man` page:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>                Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep)

**Edit**

Since you asked this question, `@Sriram P` updated the question via a comment below asking how to also exclude the line `0 new messages sent`.

With this in mind, here is an updated pattern that should better meet the original requirement, and also exclude `0 new messages sent`:

```
grep -E '^([0-9]+ )?messages sent( [0-9]+)?$' myfile.txt
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: what if my data file has " 0 new messages sent" and i don't want this line also in output

Comment: Okay, this is a new requirement. You have a couple of options - the quick 'n' dirty solution would be to pipe the result to another `grep` call doing an "invert match" (`-v`) for that string to filter it out; i.e: `grep -E '^messages sent|messages sent$' myfile.txt | grep -v '0 new messages sent'`.

Comment: or grep for `[0-9] messages sent$`

Comment: Not exactly - that won't match `messages sent 4321`. However, you got me thinking properly about the question - I think this should work better: `grep -E '^([0-9]+ )?messages sent( [0-9]+)?$' myfile.txt`. Of course that also matches the string 'messages sent', but that's something of an edge case. I'll update my answer!